# convert array of json label in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of JSON like

```
 [
{title:'button'},
{title:'button'},
{title:'button'},
{title:'button'},
]
```

and want to convert it as

```
[
{title:'button 1'},
{title:'button 2'},
{title:'button 3'},
{title:'button 4'},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please

```
    var arrJson = [
{title:'button'},
{title:'button'},
{title:'button'},
{title:'button'},
] ,

arrJson.forEach((e,i)=>{
    arrJson [i]['title'] = arrJson[i]['title'] + " " + i;
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple map to mutate each object in the array by adding the index:

```js
[{ title: 'button' }, { title: 'button' }, { title: 'button' }, { title: 'button' }].map(
  (obj, idx) => {
    obj.title = `${obj.title} ${idx + 1}`;
    return obj;
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.map`:

```
arr.map(({ title }, i) => ({ title: `${title} ${i + 1}`}));
```